# Can each of Jenkins-slave(kubernetes pod) to be bound to one build job while keep it alive even finished the job

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, jenkins-agent

We are using kubernetes plugin for Jenkins to construct a special CI system. We want to achieve that:

1. For a given build job(named *job_A*), it will be built more than one time;
2. We hope this job *job_A* to be bound to a specific jenkins-slave(named *pod_A*), and the *pod_A* should only provide service for *job_A*.
3. After the *job_A* finished the build, *pod_A* should keep alive for the period of time *time_T*;
4. During the *time_T*, the pod_A should not build other jobs even through it is idle.
5. After another time interval which is less than *time_T*(the *pod_A* is still alive), we want to re-build the *job_A*, it will be send to *pod_A* and be build there.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: If having a specific identity to jenkins-slave, in this case pods, is an issue then that can be achieved using a controller type called `StatefulSets`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the PodTemplate definition there is an option idle time *Time in minutes to retain slave when idle* (`time_T`) that you can set to a large value.

Then set the label of the pod template to a unique value and same label in your job. That way that pod will only take builds of that job

Comment: @terry Where can I set the label in the job?